# Ubuntu for a Dell D630 laptop with no Windows

Tags: system-installation, windows, dell

Someone gave me a Dell D630 laptop with Windows totally removed. How will that effect Ubuntu installation?

I'm not tech inclined, but I can follow instructions and I've got nothing to lose but time.

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu is a linux operating system, just like Windows is a operating system.
You do not need windows installed to use Ubuntu.

All you need to simply get started is a live DVD or bootable USB and choose to boot from it when you turn the laptop on.

It's a simple walk through and choices from there on out.
You can try Ubuntu live and then install it from there or install it directly from the supplied boot options.

Comment: It really is. I also used to own that laptop.. a few times over back in the day. I lost one out of a helicopter once over the water.... Keep that sucker strapped down lol

Also, use lubuntu or xubuntu if you are considering using ubuntu linux for that laptop. It's much more efficient on that laptop.

The best one I've found is LXLE. Basically, a distro built on the latest LTS releases of ubuntu, with the performance and lightweight usage of lubuntu, while being packed with all the programs out of the box that you'll ever need to get going.

Answer (score 0):

As indicated by @mydarkthawts,
Windows and Ubuntu are two different OS, so if one is missing, the other one runs fine, since most of machines are designed to run only one OS.

In case you want to install Ubuntu, I recommend you to do it from a USB hard drive having the Ubuntu OS iso flashed on it.

You can flash the Ubuntu OS iso on a USB hard drive by using [Balena Etcher](https://www.balena.io/etcher/) (it is super user-friendly) or similar programs, then you can plug it in your PC, turn it on, access the BIOS and change the booting sequence in order to have your PC boot from your USB hard drive.

This [thread](https://askubuntu.com/a/1366167/1342430) indicates the steps to take one by one. It might help you.