# How to reinstall Ubuntu on a PC without internet connection and having Ubuntu Server version OS (no Desktop GUI) from a iso got via USB drive

Tags: boot, system-installation, usb, iso

I want to reinstall Ubuntu on a PC (let's call it PC_1) running Ubuntu Server OS (No GUI) that cannot connect to the internet.

To do so, I have downloaded [Ubuntu 18.04 iso](https://releases.ubuntu.com/18.04/ubuntu-18.04.6-desktop-amd64.iso) from another PC, but I am not sure what to do then.

I have flashed the iso on a USB drive with [Balena Etcher](https://www.balena.io/etcher/), but then I don't know how to go on.

I guess I should connect the USB drive to PC_1, locate the USB drive and run something from the command prompt to tell the PC to install Ubuntu OS from the USB drive....

Which commands should I run?

Comment: Are you able to boot PC_1 from the USB drive? If so, you should be able to install Ubuntu 18.04.6 Desktop (the .iso version you linked)  from there.

Comment: Thaaks, I was lacking the concept of booting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED

I was missing a very basic concept of installing OSs, doing it by booting!

By following [Sakitech's tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lIF8e_5F9B4), I

1. turned my PC on,
2. started pressing `F2` continuosly as the PC firm logo and a loading bar was showing up.
    This activated the BIOS menu.
3. From here, I changed settings in menu `system > Boot sequence` in order to have the PC trying to boot first from USB storage drive, then from HDD. (I used key `space` to insert or remove the booting source from the sequence, and keys `U` and `D` to move the sources up and down along the boot sequence.
4. Then I pressed `esc` and selected `save and exit`, as a menu popped up asking me if I wanted to save the settings.
5. Then I shut down the PC from the power button, turned it on again,

and finally the PC booted from my USB storage drive containing having the Ubuntu 18.04 iso flashed on it.
A guided procedure starts asking the user how to configure the new OS, I just did it to the end, restarted the PC as asked by the guided procedure, and I finally managed to install the OS.